# Rails View Undefined Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to

A little background for my app. I have users that have 1 quiz and a quiz that belongs to a user. I am trying to list the quizzes that the users have taken but I get an error.

NoMethodError in Users#index

Showing /Users/Daniel/Documents/cis196/CollegeConnection/app/views/users/index.html.erb where line #24 raised:

undefined method `userName' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #24):

```
<% @user.each do |u| %>
  <tr>
    <td><h6><%= u.quiz.userName%></h6></td>
    <td><h6><%= u.quiz.q1 %></h6></td>
    <td><% for q in u.quiz.q2 %>
      <% if q != nil %>
```

Rails.root: /Users/Daniel/Documents/cis196/CollegeConnection

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/users/index.html.erb:24:in `block in _app_views_users_index_html_erb__3921348574137420689_70261694365660'
app/views/users/index.html.erb:22:in`_app_views_users_index_html_erb__3921348574137420689_70261694365660'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:25:in `index'

Here's some relavent code.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_one :quiz, :class_name => 'Quiz'

attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :position, :remember_me
validates :name, :presence => true
validates_length_of :name, :maximum=>30
validates :name, :format => { :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/,
:message => "Only letters allowed" }
validates_presence_of :position
validates :email, :presence => true
validates :email, :uniqueness => true

scope :college,    where(position: 'College')
scope :highschool, where(position: 'High School')

end


class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

validates :q1, :presence => true
validates :q2, :presence => true
validates :q3, :presence => true
serialize :q2
has_many :activities



 end

def create
@quiz = current_user.quizzes.build(params[:quiz])
# @quiz = Quiz.new(params[:quiz])
@quiz.userName=current_user.name
@activities = Activity.all

respond_to do |format|
  if @quiz.save
    format.html { redirect_to @quiz, notice: 'Thank You for Taking the Quiz!.' }
    format.json { render json: @quiz, status: :created, location: @quiz }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @quiz.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

<% @user.each do |u| %>
<tr>
  <td><h6><%= u.quiz.userName%></h6></td>
  <td><h6><%= u.quiz.q1 %></h6></td>
  <td><% for q in u.quiz.q2 %>
  <% if q != nil %>
    <h6><%= q  %></h6>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<td><h6><%= u.quiz.q3 %></h6></td>
<td>X</td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

This is the view with the error. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the instance variable @user from your view but you don't instatiate it anywhere in your controller, therefore it's nil (doesn't exist).

In the controller that calls the view file, you have to instatiate the variable like this:

```
# assuming you've already did something like
# @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id]
# in order to retrieve the quiz
@user = @quiz.user
```

This should make @user available in the view. For more info refer to the ActiveRecord Associations guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I still get the same error. Any other thoughts? Oh and to note, the view is a user view, not a quiz view.

Comment: The error shows that the problem occurred in the 'index' controller action, but the pasted code is the 'create' action (and it looks like the create action from the QuizController, rather than the UserController...), so any suggestions to alter it (by assigning values to @user in there) is unlikely to work)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are traversing @user, so that means @user is an array object (probably an array of users).

You have to check if the @user is properly initialized in the controller action or in the view. In this case, check if @user is set in users_controller, action "index".

Also, since it's an array of users, please use @users not @user.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that line 24 is the line:

```
<td><h6><%= u.quiz.userName%></h6></td>
```

Since the error is telling you that "nil" doesn't have a ".userName" method, the thing that's trying to have that method called on it must be nil. So in your iteration of users, one of them most likely does not have a ".quiz".

If you use ruby-debug you can point a breakpoint on that line an inspect all the values (or just use "puts u.quiz.inspect" to dump it to the console.